# Moving draggable element between relatively positioned containers

Tags: html, css, jquery-ui, draggable

I have a page containing items that can be dropped into various containers. I have to prepend the draggable item to the container it is currently over at any given time in order to style it in a certain way according to the css, dependent on a combination of the draggable's and the drop target's class. Applying this style in javascript isn't an option - the styling has to come from CSS.

The problem comes because the containers I am prepending the draggable to have the `position: relative` attribute. This messes up with the draggable helper's position relative to my mouse when I'm moving it along.

Here's a very simplified demo of the issue:

```js
$('.draggable').draggable({
  drag: _onDrag,
  helper: function () {
    return $(this).clone().prependTo('#div1');
  }
});

function _onDrag(event, ui) {
  ui.helper.hide();

  var elementAtPoint = $(document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY));

  if(elementAtPoint.hasClass('dropTarget')) {
   ui.helper.prependTo(elementAtPoint);
  }  
  
  ui.helper.show();
}
```

```css
.draggable {
 display: inline-block;
 background: red;
 height:50px;
 width: 50px;
}

#div1 .item1 {
  background: green;
}

#div1 .item2 {
  background: purple;
}

#div2 .item1 {
  background: blue;
}

#div2 .item2 {
  background: orange;  
}

#div1, #div2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="draggable item1">
  Drag me!
</div>

<div class="draggable item2">
  Drag me too!
</div>

<div id="div1" class="dropTarget">
  Drag the box here first...
</div>
<div id="div2" class="dropTarget">
  Then drag it here :(
</div>
```

Is there anything I can do to prevent the draggable from losing it's position, without changing the css or html?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the render position is recalculated based on the new offset when the DOM is rearranged. The simplest way to fix it is to not rearrange the DOM. Have you considered using `droppable` widgets? They provide the functionality you're looking for pretty much out-of-the-box:

```js
$('#draggable').draggable({
  helper: function () {
    return $(this).clone().prependTo('#div1');
  }
});
$('#div1, #div2').droppable({
  over: function(e, ui) {
    ui.helper.addClass($(this).data('target-class'));
  },
  out: function(e, ui) {
    ui.helper.removeClass($(this).data('target-class'));
  }
});
```

```css
#draggable {
 display: inline-block;
 background: red;
 height:50px;
 width: 50px;
}

#draggable.green {
  background: green;
}

#draggable.blue {
  background: blue;
}

#div1, #div2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div id="draggable">
  Drag me!
</div>

<div id="div1" class="dropTarget" data-target-class="green">
  Drag the box here first...
</div>
<div id="div2" class="dropTarget" data-target-class="blue">
  Then drag it here :)
</div>
```

Update: in order to do this without any CSS changes, you can get the difference between the containers' positions, and use it as a position offset.

```js
$('.draggable').draggable({
  start: _onStart,
  drag: _onDrag,
  helper: function () {
    return $(this).clone().prependTo('#div1');
  }
});

function _onStart(event, ui) {
  this.initialContainer = ui.helper.parent();
  this.currentContainer = ui.helper.parent();
  this.topOffset = 0;
  this.leftOffset = 0;
}

function _onDrag(event, ui) {
  ui.helper.hide();

  var elementAtPoint = $(document.elementFromPoint(event.clientX, event.clientY));

  if(elementAtPoint.hasClass('dropTarget') &&
     !elementAtPoint.is(this.currentContainer)) {

    this.topOffset = elementAtPoint.position().top -
                     this.initialContainer.position().top;
    this.leftOffset = elementAtPoint.position().left -
                      this.initialContainer.position().left;

    this.currentContainer = elementAtPoint;

 ui.helper.prependTo(elementAtPoint);
  }
  
  ui.position.top -= this.topOffset;
  ui.position.left -= this.leftOffset;
  
  ui.helper.show();
}
```

```css
.draggable {
 display: inline-block;
 background: red;
 height:50px;
 width: 50px;
}

#div1 .item1 {
  background: green;
}

#div1 .item2 {
  background: purple;
}

#div2 .item1 {
  background: blue;
}

#div2 .item2 {
  background: orange;  
}

#div1, #div2 {
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<div class="draggable item1">
  Drag me!
</div>

<div class="draggable item2">
  Drag me too!
</div>

<div id="div1" class="dropTarget">
  Drag the box here first...
</div>
<div id="div2" class="dropTarget">
  Then drag it here :)
</div>
```

I'd still recommend pushing for rewriting the CSS if at all possible. The first approach is both more readable and less fragile

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. The issue with this method is that I don't really want to apply a class to the draggable - the class of the droppable area will depend on a number of factors, and I need the draggable to be styled according to the droppable it's over, not according to a simple rule like div1 = green, etc. A droppable box might have any of twentyish different classes depending on the context the page is loaded in, and the draggable should display differently in each one, according to the rules encoded in the css.

Comment: As for the ID, I appreciate it's a bad idea and am not doing it in my actual code, I just threw the example together pretty quickly and didn't really give the  selectors I was using any thought.

Comment: To clarify a bit, suppose there were two draggables here - one of them needs to work exactly as you've demonstrated. The second one, with a class of "secondDraggable" needs to instead go purple in one box, and orange in the other. Rules for "firstDraggable" and "secondDraggable" being displayed correctly inside their drop spaces already exist in the css, I just need to make them apply as I'm dragging the boxes around.

Comment: I updated the snippet in the question to clarify for you and/or any future viewers.

Comment: Well, to do it this way you'd have to manually recalculate the helper's position using the difference between the containers as an offset. I'd urge you to rewrite the CSS -- it will make not only this but also future updates easier

Comment: I suspected something along these lines would be the answer. I agree it's not very nice but right now changing the CSS isn't an option. Thanks for dealing with the slightly unclear question.